# Mutability in Python and why it happens?

Tags: python, list, immutability

So Im trying get mutability a bit better into my brain and I saw quite a lot of experienced people struggle sometimes.

I made this little test code here:

```
x = 1
def test():
    x = 2
test()
print(x) #1


x = 1
def test():
    global x
    x = 2
test()
print(x) #2


x = [1]
def test():
    x = [2]
test()
print(x) #[1]


x = [1]
def test():
    global x
    x = [2]
test()
print(x) # [2]


x = [1]
def test():
    x[0] = 2
test()
print(x) #[2]
```

Everything is clear to me except what the difference between the last and second last could be. What exactly is the rule to this. I noticed that it is possible to change the value of the object but not the object type itself or did I understand this wrong?

Comment: `x=[2]` does not mutate `x` in-place. `x[0]=2` mutates list. `x[0]` calls `.__setitem__()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# case 1
x = 1
def test():
    x = 2
test()
print(x) #1

# case 2
x = 1
def test():
    global x
    x = 2
test()
print(x) #2
```

In case 1, the variable `x` inside `test` is locally scoped hence changing its values does not change the value of x declared outside `test` and hence doesn't mutate `x` which is declared outside `test`.

In case 2, the variable `x` inside `test` is globally scoped hence changing its values does change the value of x declared outside `test` and hence does mutate `x` outside `test`.

---

```
# case 3
x = [1]
def test():
    global x
    x = [2]
test()
print(x) # [2]

# case 4
x = [1]
def test():
    x[0] = 2
test()
print(x) #[2]
```

In case 3, the list `x` inside `test` is globally scoped at holds a reference to the list outside `test`, but when you assign a new list to `x`, a new reference is created to this list `[2]` and mutating this new list doesn't mutates the value in the list declared outside `test`.

In case 4, the list `x` inside the `test` method holds reference to the same instance of list which is declared outside the function `test`, when you call `x[0]` you are not changing the reference to the list but rather you are assigning the value `2` to `index 0` inside the same list, which mutates the outside list.